# Get time since Call start in AGI

Tags: asterisk, agi

When I have call request in AGI script, is it possible to get time since call was created? For example, if it was routed sequentially through several softswitches can I get whole time sinse first softswitch or since generation in remote softphone ?
SIP only is used.
I also use AMI, and in CDR event I see that `(Duration - BillableSeconds)` is sometimes longer (for 10-20 seconds) then time from AGI request to Up, so duration may be already includes some time before call passed to my Asterisk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no way determine any history of call before it go your switch unless other switch inform you about by special headers.

No, CDR(duration) is counted from time when call arived to asterisk. CDR(billsec) always less or equal to duration.